# Scala for loop - by 2*i in the next loop

Tags: scala

This is probably a basic scala question but not able to figure out how:

How can this java loop be expressed using Scala for:

```
for (int i=1;i<100000;i=2*i)
```

I understand this is one possible way:

```
  def loopByTwiceBefore(from:Int, to:Int)(f:Int=>Unit):Unit = {
    if (from<to){
        f(from)
        loopByTwiceBefore(from*2, to)(f);
    }
  }
```

But is there a more canonical way to do this in Scala.

Comment: I guess you mean `int i=1` instead of `int i=0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `iterate` function from `Iterator` (or from other classes like `Stream`, `List` etc.):

```
Iterator.iterate(1)(_*2).takeWhile(_ < 100000) foreach {...}
```

Comment: `for (n <- Iterator.iterate(1)(2*).takeWhile(100000>)) {...}`

Comment: @KimStebel: I think you mean `2*_` instead of `2**`

Comment: Thanks sschaef and @KimStebel - both your answer works nicely

Comment: One should note that postfix ops need a feature flag in 2.10, thus I suggest not to use them in this situation.

Comment: `2*` and `10000>` are not postfix ops. They work fine without a feature flag in 2.10.0-M6. Anyway, feature flags are not some kind of warning, it's perfectly ok to enable them.

Comment: @KimStebel: I get a warning, but I'm using a nightly build of Scala. Maybe they did some changes here since M6.